# Can I possible to implement Annotator using iFrame?

Tags: annotatorjs

**I need to implement in my Angular 4 application,**

*Reference for Annotator* 
http://annotatorjs.org/

I just can only find this reference 
https://github.com/aron/annotator.touch.js/issues/6

Anyone can help Me..? if possible, please share the methods to implement!!!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but you need to authenticate to work with it.
Ref: http://docs.annotatorjs.org/en/v1.2.x/authentication.html
For to get consumer key and secret you need to sign up with Annotate It.
*http://annotateit.org/*

But it is outdated, and shows like If you have an AnnotateIt account, you can still log in, but we are now closed for signups.

Comment: ThanQ madonna!, n i just found the same!!